# BindingSource changing data after PropertyChangedEvent

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, infragistics

I have some controls bound to a `Windows.Forms.BindingSource`. The bound data is a class which communicates with a database and implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged`-interface. I implemented it like this:

```
public class MyClass: INotifyPropertyChanged {

public String Bezeichnung 
{
    get => _row["bez"].ToString();
    set
    {
        if (value == null)
           _row["bez"] = DBNull.Value;
        else
           _row["bez"] = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
     }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String name = "")
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
...
```

Inside my form I have a `ValueChanged`-event for a third-party Combobox (Infragistics UltraCombo). This Combobox is e.g. bound to the property `Bezeichnung`.
The weird thing now is, that when I change another property of the db-class inside the `ValueChanged` event, it raises the event again and sets the Combobox-value back to what it was before. So I cannot change the value of the Combo as its resets it every time.

```
private void Combo_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   ... 
   dbclass.Otherproperty = 42.9; 
   // after changing this and raising the PropertyChangedEvent,
   // this function gets called again (the value of the combo is back to its init value)
}
```

I assume it has something to do with the raise of the `PropertyChangedEvent` inside my db-class as it somehow "commits" all data and the BindindSource is rebinding all pending data. Changing the binding to `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged` doesnt work either.

Comment: Try to call the `NotifyPropertyChanged();` only if the value is changes like: `set  { if (value == null) {  _row["bez"] = DBNull.Value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } else if (_row["bez"] != value) {  _row["bez"] = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }`

Comment: No change. It doesnt even go into the setter of the property as is rechanges the combo-value before even noticing the db-class.

Comment: There are two problems I figured out: 1. when firing `PropertyChanged` the BindingSource does not regard the Property-Name that has been changed. It validates all properties (although the Property-name has been passed as an argument in the `PropertyChangedEventArgs`. 2. the Combo fires ValueChanged without changing the bound value. The bound value is being commited when loosing focus. Changing `DataSourceUpdateMode` does nothing.